# Add date form another table to a query

Tags: mysql

My table is a list of printers. Another table is a list of service dates (in the past and in the future).

```
SELECT p.*, s.date AS service_date
FROM printer p
LEFT JOIN services s
    ON s.printer = p.id
WHERE
    s.date > NOW()
ORDER BY
    service_date ASC
```

gives me multiple rows.
I want only the next upcoming date in the list. That means the next service date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another `JOIN` condition, that uses a correlated subquery to ensure that you are joining with thet correct record (ie the first record with a date in the future):

```
SELECT p.*, s.date AS service_date 
FROM printer p 
LEFT JOIN services s 
    ON s.printer = p.id 
    AND s.date > NOW()
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM services s1
        WHERE s1.printer = p.id 
        AND s1.date > NOW()
        AND s1.date < s.date
    )
ORDER BY service_date ASC
```

Note: since you are using `LEFT JOIN`, all conditions on the joined table must go in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`, not in the `WHERE` clause (else, you are actually performing an `INNER JOIN`). I fixed that.

Comment: Great! Thank you. The addition with the `INNER JOIN` means, when I use the ` WHERE` clause it is not effecting the `LEFT JOIN` because it could be empty, correct?

Comment: @T.Karter: yes, if you put a condition on a LEFT JOINed table in the WHERE clause, it will not allow empty values. This defeats the LEFT JOIN, which exists to allow non-matching records.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of handling this would be to use analytic functions.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.*, s.date AS service_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY s.date DESC) rn
    FROM printer p
    LEFT JOIN services s ON s.printer = p.id
    WHERE s.date > NOW()
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This would return, for each printer, the record corresponding to the most recent service date.  If instead I misunderstood and you want the oldest, change the `ORDER BY` clause in the call to `ROW_NUMBER` above.